# Starting GUI Apps from Terminal, keeping the same terminal for other use

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome

When we start some GUI apps from the terminal, it gets started up. For instance I run nautilus from terminal. I type:
    `user@system ~$: nautilus`
It gets started. But the terminal keeps printing its logs and errors. Is it possible to avoid this and start the process seperately, keeping the terminal for other use? I have many programs to start from the terminal with command line options. This brings many terminals and it all become clumpsy and hard to switch between apps. So how to start a GUI process/app seperately from terminal. Running GNOME 3.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way is to start it like this:

```
nautilus --your --paremeters --here < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown -a
```

You can run the disown once for all jobs if you prefer.

Comment: Could you please explain whats going on?